# Redirect to Route using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using `react-router` in my ReactJS application. I'm trying to redirect a particular route using `react-router`. Here is the code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route component={ShowPost} path="/"></Route>
        <Route component={AddPost} path="/addPost"></Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

But I really can't figure out how to redirect to a particular route programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to import Link from 'react-router'.

See https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/05-active-links

```
<Link to="/" > Home </Link>
<Link to="/addPost"> Add Post </Link>
```

If you mean Redirect you can check 
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md